# How to get extra parameters in a Django Rest Framework ViewSet

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have to implement an end-point with Django Rest Framework that receives extra parameters this way:

`GET .../hotels_in_period/?check_in=2018-09-30&check_out=2018-10-10`

The end-point should receive both parameters `check-in` and `check-out`, but I don't know how to get them in the `list` method of the viewset. I thought they would be available as `request.data`, but they are not.

I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [**`request.query_params`**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#query_params)

From the doc

> **`request.query_params`** is a more correctly named synonym for
>   **`request.GET`**.
>
> For clarity inside your code, we recommend using `request.query_params`
>   instead of the Django's standard `request.GET`. Doing so will help keep
>   your codebase more correct and obvious - any HTTP method type may
>   include query parameters, not just `GET` requests

example:

```
class TagsAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        search = request.query_params.get('search')
        if search:
            data = get_paginated_data(
                data=TagSerializer(
                    Tag.objects.filter(name__contains=search).annotate(posts_count=Count('posts')).order_by(
                        '-posts_count').exclude(posts__isnull=True), many=True).data,
                page=request.query_params.get('page'),
                limit=request.query_params.get('limit'),
                url=F"/social/tags/?search={search}"
            )
        else:
            data = get_paginated_data(
                data=TagSerializer(
                    Tag.objects.all().annotate(posts_count=Count('posts')).order_by('-posts_count').exclude(
                        posts__isnull=True),
                    many=True).data,
                page=request.query_params.get('page'),
                limit=request.query_params.get('limit'),
                url=F"/social/tags/?"
            )
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot